# responsive center logo with menu button on right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this look where the logo is centered and the menu button is on the right.

[image]

Here is what i have tried. I either center both the items or none. The other thing i was able to do was have the image left aligned and the menu button right aligned.

The goal is to have the image centered and the menu button right aligned

**HTML**

```css
.topnav {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.topnav nav{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    width:100%;
}

.topnav nav div{
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    margin-right: 7.5% ;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700; /* this is futura heavy*/
    width:11.25%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    word-wrap:true;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    /*line-height: 5em;*/
}

.notlink {
    width:30.4%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.notlink img {
    width: 100%;
}

.topnav nav .link:hover {
    color: #008ed2;
}

.icon {
    display: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myTopnav a.link {display: none;}
    
    .topnav nav div{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .icon {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .notlink {
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
    }
    .notlink img {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:75px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myTopnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .myTopnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .myTopnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
                <nav>
                    <div class="myTopnav" id="myTopnav">
                        <a class="link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        <a class="link" id ="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                        <a class="link" href="expertise.html">EXPERTISE</a>
                        <a class="notlink" href="index.html"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/earth-day-2017-5650394117046272-s.png"></a>
                        <a class="link" href="industries.html">INDUSTRIES</a>
                        <a class="link" href="friends.html">FRIENDS OF MARY</a>
                        <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="topNav()">&#9776;</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Here is the [FIDDILE](https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox in your media query:

```
.icon {
  display :inline-block; /*or inline works as well*/
  position : absolute;
  right : 0;
}

.notlink {
    width: 70%;
    display : flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content : center;
}
.notlink img {
    /*removed display inline-block*/
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:75px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/6/)

Comment: This centers the logo but the menu button is not right aligned.

Comment: Okay that got the images to be aligned but issue with actaully showing the menu now.... https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/8/

Comment: how should the mobile menu look like?

Comment: here is the link to that separate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571444/responsive-menu-not-showing/43572342#43572342

Answer (score 1):

there is a few option,

`text-align` for the logo and setting the burger in `absolute` makes it easy.

here is an example .

```css
/* show me center */

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to left, white 50%,gray 50%);
}

/* layout */
.topnav {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.topnav nav{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    width:100%;
}

.topnav nav div{
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    margin-right: 7.5% ;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700; /* this is futura heavy*/
    width:11.25%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    word-wrap:true;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    /*line-height: 5em;*/
}

.notlink {
    width:30.4%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.notlink img {
    width: 100%;
}

.topnav nav .link:hover {
    color: #008ed2;
}

.icon {
    display: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myTopnav a.link {display: none;}
 /* update */   
    .topnav nav div{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      text-align:center;
    }
    
    .icon {
        position: absolute;
      z-index:1;
      left:auto;
      left:100%;
      top:50%;
      transform:translate(-200%,-50%);
        display: inline-block;
    }
    /* end update */
    .notlink {
    }
    .notlink img {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:75px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
                <nav>
                    <div class="myTopnav" id="myTopnav">
                        <a class="link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        <a class="link" id ="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                        <a class="link" href="expertise.html">EXPERTISE</a>
                        <a class="notlink" href="index.html"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/earth-day-2017-5650394117046272-s.png"></a>
                        <a class="link" href="industries.html">INDUSTRIES</a>
                        <a class="link" href="friends.html">FRIENDS OF MARY</a>
                        <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="topNav()">&#9776;</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

[snippet turned into a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/5/)

Comment: The menu button does not appear to be right aligned

Comment: @codeNinja well update coordonates to set it wherever you need it   :) , answer  was about a method to set the logo at center.