# responsive menu not showing

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I want to show the menu items as seperate rows on smaller screen. This is pretty basic and seen many places. The effect i am going for is:

[image]

With what i have so far (code Below) the menu items just show up next to the logo (thats how they are there for desktop).

**Also i need to add a Background Image to the menus items. One image that fills the entire area and not the same image repeating for each menu**

I have already added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/8/)

```js
//make the topnav responsive for mobile screens
function topNav() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "myTopnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "myTopnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.topnav nav{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    width:100%;
}

.topnav nav div{
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    margin-right: 7.5% ;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700; /* this is futura heavy*/
    width:11.25%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    word-wrap:true;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    /*line-height: 5em;*/
}

.notlink {
    width:30.4%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.notlink img {
    width: 100%;
}

.topnav nav .link:hover {
    color: #008ed2;
}

.icon {
    display: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myTopnav a.link {display: none;}
    
    .topnav nav div{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .icon {
      display :inline-block;
      position : absolute;
      right : 0;
    }
    
    .notlink {
        width: 70%;
        display : flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content : center;
    }
    .notlink img {
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:75px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myTopnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .myTopnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .myTopnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
                <nav>
                    <div class="myTopnav" id="myTopnav">
                        <a class="link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        <a class="link" id ="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                        <a class="link" href="expertise.html">EXPERTISE</a>
                        <a class="notlink" href="index.html"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/earth-day-2017-5650394117046272-s.png"></a>
                        <a class="link" href="industries.html">INDUSTRIES</a>
                        <a class="link" href="friends.html">FRIENDS OF MARY</a>
                        <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="topNav()">&#9776;</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: please look at this, it's really not clean and has some unnessecary code now and it needs some refactoring, but i just had little time. will refactor/do it better  and pack it into an answer tomorrow if it is what you need?: https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/13/

Comment: i just read your question again nad my previous shared fiddle is propably not what you want.you want to keep the logo at the top and insert another image as menu background right?

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: Sorry for the late answer checkt this out: https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/14/

Comment: There is an error in the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/16/ this one is better. now you just need to position it correctly over the rest of your content when it's expanded

Comment: thanks oliver. That did the trick. Can you please submit that as an answer so that i can accept it for future searchers.

Comment: I Added the  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution (changed markup, js and css):

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav" data-mobile="false">
  <nav>
    <div class="myTopnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a class="link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a class="link" id ="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="link" href="expertise.html">EXPERTISE</a>
      <a class="notlink" href="index.html"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/earth-day-2017-5650394117046272-s.png"></a>
      <a class="link" href="industries.html">INDUSTRIES</a>
      <a class="link" href="friends.html">FRIENDS OF MARY</a>
      <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="topNav()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <nav id="mobile-menu">
      <a class="link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a class="link" id ="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="link" href="expertise.html">EXPERTISE</a>
      <a class="link" href="industries.html">INDUSTRIES</a>
      <a class="link" href="friends.html">FRIENDS OF MARY</a>
      <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function topNav() {
  var topNav = document.querySelector('.topnav');
  topNav.dataset.mobile = (topNav.dataset.mobile == "false") ? true : false;
}
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height : 100%;
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  background-color : white;
}

.topnav {
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.topnav nav:first-of-type{
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  width:100%;
}

.topnav .myTopnav{
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  margin-right: 7.5% ;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700; /* this is futura heavy*/
  width:11.25%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  word-wrap:true;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  /*line-height: 5em;*/
}

.notlink {
  width:30.4%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.notlink img {
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav nav .link:hover {
  color: #008ed2;
}

.icon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
}

#mobile-menu {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  padding : 20px;
  background: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/638771889339404289/h64dZ4wh_400x400.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*justify-content: center; --> add this to center vertically*/ 
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

#mobile-menu > * {
  color : black;
}

.topnav[data-mobile=false] #mobile-menu {
  display : none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .myTopnav a.link {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav[data-mobile=true]{
    height : 100%;
  }

  .topnav nav div{
    width: 100%;
    height : 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .icon {
    display :inline-block;
    position : absolute;
    right : 0;
  }

  .notlink {
    width: 70%;
    display : flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content : center;
  }

  .notlink img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:75px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

After this you need to place it correctly over your following content when the mobile menu is expanded.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyexzhao/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/uuc64Lqv/1/)

You need to add `flex-direction:column` for topbar inorder to show it as column for mobile devices.

```
    .topnav nav div{
      flex-direction:column;
    }
    .myTopnav.responsive a.link:first-child{
      margin-top:30px;
    }
    .myTopnav.responsive a.link{
      width : 100%;
    }
    .myTopnav.responsive a.notlink{
          width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: not sure if it is just me but in the fiddle clicking the menu button is not doing anything.

Comment: Hi @codeNinja, I have updated the fiddle, check it now.

Comment: The only thing is that the background image should fill the full screen. Right now it only fills the high of the menu.

Comment: the new update you made moves the logo. The logo should stay in place. The menu drawer should over to cover the full screen height. See in the image i have shown that the wood background fills the full page

Comment: I didnt understand. In first fiddle, the google logo stays at top and the background black color image occupies screen. In second fiddle, logo comes in center. Do you want the google logo cover the entire screen, both in width and height?